# Django - Queryset to get fields from extended User model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have **model Profile that extends User** and I'd like to "join" User model to get some fields from it. I understand that it would not be joining because Profile is an extension of User, but I'm not sure how to make it work. Appreciate any help on this.

Basically, the goal is to get from User and Profile these fields: **username (from User) last_login (from User), last_activity (from Profile) in a form of queryset for my view.**

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    last_activity = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)  # <- this part not correct, but not sure how to treat User model here

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('__all__')
```

**views.py**

```
class ProfileList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.values('id', 'user__username', 'user__last_login', 'last_activity')  # <- this isn't right, not sure what would be the correct way
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def profile(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    username = profile.user.username
    last_login = profile.user.last_login
    last_activity = profile.last_activity
    return render(request, "user.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to the **models.py**

```
    from django.db.models.signals import post_save
    from django.dispatch import receiver

    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
        last_activity = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
       
        @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
        def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
          if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    
        @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
        def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
            instance.profile.save()
```

and in the case you want to change something in the **views.py** this an example how you can do it:

```
   from datetime import datetime
    def update_profile(request, user_id):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        user.profile.last_activity = datetime.now()
        user.save()
```

I wich this help you

Comment: Thank you - I already added signals and they are working. The task I have right now is to understand how to get from User and Profile these fields: ```username``` (from User) ```last_login``` (from User), ```last_activity``` (from Profile) in a form of queryset for my view.

Comment: To get to Profile from user, you can do something like `User.profile.last_activity` for last login should be should be In User Model.

Comment: sorry for the late i just see your comment .in the case you still didn't resolve it.Like any queryset by this User.objects.filter(username="your username"),and vice versa for the others.